# SQL statement INNER JOIN to Django ORM

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Django but my sql is working fine. I wonder how i can make such query in Django

I have SQL statement with join

```
select a.id,
       b.id
from model.a 
join model.b on model.b.a_id=model.a.id
where 'need to find'=Any(a.info);
```

Models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    info = models.ArrayField()

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    a = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='a', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What is `=Any(a.info)` supposed to do?

Comment: Note that usually a Django query returns a queryset of *objects*, not tuples. While that is possible, it is not very elegant. Likely here you want to obtain the `B` objects where the `.a` is already filled in, such that it is a single query to get the `B` model objects that match, and the corresponding `A` object.

Comment: It also is not a good idea to work with an `ArrayField`: database normalization rules basically want to convert composite values into a separate table and links to that model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Start with [`queries`in `django`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) and you probably want to look specifically for [lookups-that-span-relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: You don't join in Django, Django joins for you. Please explain in your own words what you are trying to do **with your models**.

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
B.objects.filter(a__info__contains=['need to find']).select_related('a')
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.

This will return a `QuerySet` of `B` objects where the `A` object is loaded in the same query. It is thus possible two `B` objects refer to the same `A` object.

We here make use of the [**`__contains`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains) to check if `'need to find'` is an item of the array `info`.

The modeling however is not normalized effectively. In a normalized database, typically arrays, etc. are modeled by an extra model and `ForeignKey`s, this makes the database smaller, more efficient, and usually more predictable.